# Error 1334 from installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I had an app A for which I created an installer A1. This has been in use for many months.

We now realized that AI used to package some files - d1,d2,d3 which are not needed.

Therefore we removed them from our project and created an installer A2 which does not package the above mentioned unwanted files. (atleast thats what we expect)

Things are ok when I use this installer the usual way...but when I use this for a silent install, I get the following error:

Error 1334. The file d1 cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file 'myMedia1.cab'. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

I googled this and saw that people usually encounter this whn u release a patch or some installer release where some files are removed or moved around.

Apparently, msiexec tries to reference some cached version of these variables and since it still looks for the missing files in the new installer, install fails.

Is there a way to tackle this?  - like some way to have msiexec use just the .msi file I provide in the input rather some cached version.

Thanks...

Comment: Make sure you are using one of the established [upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370579(v=vs.85).aspx) types and are implementing it correctly. Also make sure you are following the component design and change rules. (See the links for item 2.2 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372825(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could receive this error if you haven't updated the PackageCode, ProductCode, or UpgradeCode for your A2 installer.  If A1 is installed, and then A2 runs with the same PackageCode, ProductCode, and UpgradeCode the system thinks you are running the A1 installer again and will look for the cached A1 msi under C:\windows\installer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else like me that is experiencing the same problem ([Error 1334](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-error-messages)) when building a Setup project and didn't find any explanations or solutions, here's a thread that solved my problem:

https://www.itninja.com/question/1334-error-tried-just-about-everything-i-can-think-of-anyone-know-of-some-obscure-causes

Basically, the solution to the problem is to “touch” all the files referenced in the Setup project (that is, all the dependencies - DLLs and all else). You can find the list and path of all the files in the build output, on lines like these:

```
2>  Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Threading.dll" to "C:\Path\To\Your\Project\bin\Debug\System.Threading.dll".
```

To “touch” the files, you may use [this technique](/questions/6432089/touch-file-to-update-the-date-time-of-file-modified-date-windowsxp-batchscri) or you may use some third-party file manager like [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/). You'll just need to run as administrator / accept UAC warning, because some files are in system folders.




EDIT: in my case, the problem with the Setup project began after updating some NuGet packages used by the main project.

P.S.: although I'm not using WiX, but [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects), the symptom was the same, so I hope this answer will be helpful for someone.